# Vue JS applying parent stylesheet to imported component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm just getting started with Vue JS and I'm performing a pretty basic component import like this:

```
<script>
import footer from '@/templates/footer.vue'
export default {
    components: {
        footer
    }
}
</script>

<style>
    @import '@/css/style.css';
</style>
```

The problem is that the styles from `style.css` isn't being applied to the elements inside `footer.vue`. How can I apply the styles from `style.css` to elements inside `footer.vue`?

Thanks!

**Update**

The footer component just looks like this:

```
<template >
    <view id="footer_outer_container">
        ...
    </view> 
</template>

<script>
    export default {
       name: "footer",
       props: {},
       methods: {}
    }
 </script>
 <style>

 </style>
```

And the CSS is just a regular style.css file some classes and styles.

Comment: Can you show your footer component and style.css code please?

Comment: Just added them :)

Comment: You should include that style file in style code section, like you had included it in the first example

Comment: But the problem is I have different parent pages which have their own unique imported stylesheets and they apply different styles to the footer component. So I can't import all of them into the component style section.